# How can GCN model be applied to find next link based on similarity of values between its edges?

Tags: data-visualization, multilevel-analysis, graph-neural-network, geometric-deep-learning

I want to apply GCN model to predict next link based on similarity of values between its neighbors nodes. For example I have total of 13 nodes and edges = [
(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3), (3, 4), (3, 5), (4, 5), (5, 6), (5, 7), (6, 7),
(7, 8), (7, 9), (8, 9), (9, 10), (9, 13), (10, 11), (10, 12), (10, 13),
(11, 12), (11, 13), (12, 13)
].If each node has two features = torch.tensor([
[22, 45],
[11, 34],
[25, 35],
[22, 34],
[13, 40],
[24, 45],
[10, 36],
[16, 42],
[13, 39],
[25, 44],
[22, 50],
[15, 49],
[18, 37],
], dtype=torch.float32)

I want to calculate the average of each node and compare it with its neighboring nodes i.e 1 should compare its average value only with node 1 and 2 as a result the next link should be created with node 2.In the next iteration node 2 should be considered as source node and compare its average value with its edges and predict the next link and so on.

Can anyone please explain how I can achieve this.